# My website is not crawled by google

Tags: javascript, ajax, knockout.js, web-crawler, google-crawlers

Some pages in my website are implemented using KnockoutJS (ajax JS framework)

For some reasons these pages are not crawled by Google

Pages which are not indexed:

`fidelite.kz/#!product_info/1
fidelite.kz/#!product_info/2
fidelite.kz/#!product_info/3
...
fidelite.kz/#!product_info/183`

Website has static duplicates for these pages:

`fidelite.kz/?_escaped_fragment_=product_info/1
fidelite.kz/?_escaped_fragment_=product_info/2
fidelite.kz/?_escaped_fragment_=product_info/3
...
fidelite.kz/?_escaped_fragment_=product_info/183`

Website map:

`fidelite.kz/sitemap.txt`

Please attend that page
`fidelite.kz/#!product_info/2`
is indexed because this page was added manually via google webmaster search console.
To add all page by this way is took too long time.

No errors are shown in google webmaster search console.

How to force all the pages indexed in according to sitemap.txt?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Everything about this makes me cringe.

'fidelite.kz/#!product_info/1' isn't a page fidelite.kz is the page and '#!product_info/1' is the section of the page.

Google will see the # and not index that as another page.

I would suggest that indexability is taken into consideration whenever you're design & develop any e-commerce website. If it wasn't you that made it, suggest to your client that this is an issue and a website redesign is a good solution.

Comment: Yes I did read that, great story. Please do some research about HTTP URL structure and how it relates to Google's indexing of pages.

Comment: @Alexey: Google should NOT see the part after #. If you've managed to trick Google to fetch the page then it's a bug in Google's crawlers. This is because the part after the # don't exist in the url, browsers will NEVER send it back to the server which means Google should also never do it. Browsers treat the part after # as the id of an element in your html (maybe a div or a span or a table, normally a h1, h2 or h3)

Comment: @slebetman have you ever heard about single page websites? Do you know that these websites can be indexed by google also?

Answer (score 0):

If the google search engine does not crawl your website there will be the following reasons:

1. Please check robot meta tags "noindex tag"
2. Check robots.txt file "Disallow: /"